# Getting the activity report via an API

Tags: windows, api, paypal, report

PayPal has an activity report under the 'Reports' tab on the website. We're wondering if it would be possible to generate this report and download it using an API. We have a program that imports the report into our system but don't want the risk of putting in the wrong dates and the hassel of manually downloading the file every time.

After researching the PayPal API all I can find is a thing called PayFlow, which seems to be for a different purpose.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

if you have enabled your business by integrating with PayPal Payments Pro then you can make use of the Payflow Reporting API.

This is applicable only if you have a Payflow Account.